# How do I group by rows with the same value from two different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqbEQ.png)

As can be seen, that are some equal values in some lines. I have tried to group by these rows with the following:

```
base_disc = base_disc.groupby(['iso_2', 'iso_3', 'countryname', 'país afetado', 'year', 'iso_3_afetado', 'iso_2_afetado'])[['SPS emergenciais', 'SPS regulares']].apply(sum)

base_disc = base_disc.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
```

It worked for some rows, however, some, like the following example, didn't work:
[It should be two rows and 4 "SPS Regulares" measures in 2012](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBmA4.png)

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: Are you sure that there are no trailing or leading whitespaces in the columns? better strip all columns with spaces?

Comment: better posting data sample as text so that we could reproduce it easily for you. I believe the text not really clean enough from whitespaces

Comment: Hey guys, thank you so much. The problem was trailing and leading whitespaces, as you mentioned.